# What's a paronym?

Tags: puns

I really want to know what a paronym is because we're supposed use them in class.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is a click away at [Answers.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/paronymterm.htm)

> "Two words are paronyms when their phonemic representations are similar but not identical.
>
> *(Salvatore Attardo, Linguistic Theories of Humor. Walter de Gruyter, 1994)*

You should read the whole entry.

Answer (score 3):

A paronym word is a word that derives from another word, and that has a related meaning.
It is also used for words originated from a word in a different language.

- *wisdom* with *wise*
- *angelic* with *angel*
- *carry* with *carrus*

Comment: So are migratory words also paronyms...?

Comment: @ikartik90: If you mean _migrate_ and _migration_, then yes.